# Reverb effect in android on music

Tags: android

I am currently working on a music app. I am trying to implement reverb feature in the app using [PresetReverb](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/PresetReverb.html/) class in android. I have successfully implemented the equalizer bands, Bass Booster and Virtualizer and they all are working pretty fine. But in the case of reverb it doesn't make any change to the sound.

Now, I already know that reverb effects are not present in all android devices but my device(Samsung Galaxy S4 w/ android version 5.0.1) has reverb effects in the default music player.

**Implementaion :-**

```
 ... // Three dots mean other code not relevant to question
```

***1) Music Service Class***

This is the service that handles the app.(For ex. Initialization of Audio effects)

```
public class MusicService extends Service implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

   public static PresetReverb mPresetReverb; //Here I declare the PresetReverb Effect

   ...

@Override
  public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //start playback
    mp.start();

    if (player != null) {
        ...
        mPresetReverb = new PresetReverb(1, 0);           
        ...
        mEqualizer.setEnabled(true);
    }
  }

  ...
  }
```

***2) Equalizer Activity***

This activity is used to set the audio effects

```
public class EqualizerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

...

  public void reverbPresetClicked(View view) {

          switch (view.getId()) {
             case R.id.none_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_NONE);
                break;
             case R.id.small_room_preset:    
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_SMALLROOM);
                break;
             case R.id.medium_room_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMROOM);
                break;
             case R.id.large_room_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEROOM);                    
                break;
             case R.id.plate_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_PLATE);
                break;
             case R.id.medium_hall_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_MEDIUMHALL);
                break;
            case R.id.large_hall_preset:
                MusicService.mPresetReverb.setPreset(PresetReverb.PRESET_LARGEHALL);
                break;

        }

        Log.e("Equalizer", "Preset Reverb : " + MusicService.mPresetReverb.getPreset());
        MusicService.mPresetReverb.setEnabled(true);
        MusicService.player.attachAuxEffect(MusicService.mPresetReverb.getId());
        MusicService.player.setAuxEffectSendLevel(1.0f);

    }

...

}
```

The output of the Log statement proves that the presets are being set but still no change in the sound.

If the code is correct and device is the issue, can some one send me the list of devices that supports reverb effect or if the code is faulty, someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you found out what the reason was you didn't hear any difference in sound? I have the same problem.